# dynamically auto scroll textview inside scroll view

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I am making audiobook like app and the problem is:

I have a TextView (for big story) inside ScrollView and a play audio button.
When click on audio play button, separate lines are highlighted within textview using spannablestring but when reached at the line which is last visible or partially visible text/line in screen (its not the last line of textview or story) then how to calculate scroll amount (i.e **y**) in pixels to be used in `scrollTo(x, y)`, so that line will be visible fully after scroll on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Once the text is laid out, you can use [TextView#getLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getLayout()) to get the [Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout) of the *TextView* which holds the text.

The layout can take a few forms, but you will be looking at a [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout). Within the *StaticLayout* and its super class *Layout*, you will find a number of methods that will let you know where text is within the *TextView*. You should be able to use some combinations of these methods and information about the size of the *TextView* to scroll the text.